# Add and Update Firestore Database Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a function on pressed it will check whether the database is document value exists or not, if exists it will only update the amount, if not exists it will create new data.
I tried by making log print, it works.

```
onPressed: () {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection('productstock')
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      if (doc['produckname'].toString() ==
              productname.toString() &&
          doc['productcode'].toString() ==
              productcode.toString() &&
          doc['productcategory'].toString() ==
              productcategory.toString()) {
        return print("UPDATE STOCK AMOUNT ON EXIST LIST");
      }
      return print("ADD NEW PRODUCT TO STOCK LIST");
    }
  });
},
```

[image: Print Log]

How can I make it work like when print, without duplicates and without error codes?

But when I change like this,

```
onPressed: () {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection('productstock')
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      if (doc['produckname'].toString() ==
              productname.toString() &&
          doc['productcode'].toString() ==
              productcode.toString() &&
          doc['productcategory'].toString() ==
              productcategory.toString()) {
        CollectionReference updateStock = firebaseInstance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user?.uid)
            .collection("productstock");
        updateStock.doc(doc.id).update({'stockamount': amount});
      }
      CollectionReference addStock = firebaseInstance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .collection("productstock");
      addStock.doc().set({
        'produckname': productname.toString(),
        'productcode': productcode.toString(),
        'productcategory': productcategory.toString(),
        'stockamount': amount,
      });
    }
  });
},
```

there is duplicate data, if I add 'return CollectionReference' the code can't run.

Comment: Are you just missing an `else`? I.e. `if (doc['productname']....... { ... do update... } else { .... add new doc }`.

Comment: When I make an `else` duplicate occurs.
If the doc id is exist, run update and add new doc, if doc id is not exist, run add new doc 2 times and update 1 time